# Angular2 Authguard Redirect Route Not Working

Tags: angular, routes

I created an authguard to prevent users who aren't logged in to enter a page. After the authguard runs and returns true, it doesn't redirect to the appropriate page. Am I doing something wrong?

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
                private authStatusService: AuthStatusService,
                private authService: AuthService,
                private router: Router ) { }

    canActivate(): any {

        return this.authStatusService.authStatus.subscribe(i => {
            if(i === 'auth-login-success') {
                return Observable.fromPromise(this.authService.getUser())
                    .subscribe(res => {
                        if(!res.id) {
                            this.router.navigate(['summary']);
                            return Observable.of(false);
                        }
                        return Observable.of(true);
                    },
                    error => {
                        return Observable.of(false);
                    })
            } else {
                console.log('user has not logged in')
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
                return Observable.of(false);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
                private authStatusService: AuthStatusService,
                private authService: AuthService,
                private router: Router ) { }

    canActivate(): any {

        return this.authStatusService.authStatus
        .mergeMap(i => {
            if(i === 'auth-login-success') {
                return this.authService.getUser())
                    .map(res => {
                        if(!res.id) {
                            this.router.navigate(['summary']);
                            false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        return false;
                    })
            } else {
                console.log('user has not logged in')
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .first() // not sure if this line is still necessary
    }
}
```

The router expects a `boolean`, `Promise<boolean>` or `Observable<boolean>`. 
When you call `subscribe()` you get a `Subscription` which won't work.
With `map()` an `Observable` is returned.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out @Günter Zöchbauer. This makes a lot of sense. The .first() wasn't needed and worked beautifully. However, I'm getting a typescript error with the usage of mergeMap(). I tried googling it, but wasn't able to find a solution.   `Argument of type '(i: any) => boolean | Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<any, boolean>'.
  Type 'boolean | Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any, boolean>'.
    Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any, boolean>'.`

Comment: I just saw - in `catch()` it should return `Öbservable.of(false}` instead of just `false`. Besides that I'm afraid I don't know - I'm not using TS myself except for Plunkers.